# navigate SQLite3 data base command

Tags: sql, sqlite

Ok, this is my first ever experience with sql, and I don't really know how to explain this well.

I want to run a command that will bring me to the `CHAT` database
[image]

and within the chat database, I want to get every value under `guid` and `display_name` row if the `display_name` entry is not nothing. In my picture, I would only get the `display_name` and `guid` with it for `Group I`.

[image]

What resourse can I use to look up these commands? Or can anyone tell me the commands to get this information?

Comment: I'm sorry whoever downvoted, please tell me what I can do to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT guid, display_name FROM chat WHERE display_name IS NOT ''
```